# Can I build Vuforia for WebGL to run on Mobile?

Tags: unity-webgl

I have been able to build an WebGL app using Vuforia and I could run it using github pages... BUT I get no camera.

So I've been trying to access Vuforia Configurations at runtime to select camera devices, but I can't complete a build due to not finding the "Vuforia" namespace.

So, may I build for WebGL? Can I use the camera on the browser?